# How to disable http cache in the entire site?

Tags: symfony, caching, http-caching, maintenance-mode

I need to be able to put the site in 'maintenance mode'. So I'm using a cheap hack like this one in app.php (the original app.php was moved to app.php.bak):

```
<?php
    
$key = 123;

if(isset($_GET['skip_maintenance_key']) && $_GET['skip_maintenance_key'] == $key) {
    setcookie('skip_maintenance_key', $key);
}

if(isset($_COOKIE['skip_maintenance_key']) && $_COOKIE['skip_maintenance_key'] == $key) {
    include 'app.php.bak';
    // placeholder
} else {
    //header('Cache-Control: public, maxage=30');
    header('Status: 503 Service Unavailable');
    include 'html/error/503.html';
}
```

The problem is that as soon as I hit a page that uses http cache, the page gets cached by intermediaries like Cloudflare or my own proxy and it begins to be served to everyone.

So what I would like to do is somehow disable http cache globally during maintenance, maybe adding a line of code in `// placeholder`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read Fabien saying (in a pull request that got rejected) that this should be handled by the web server. So I changed my maintenance script to modify the server config instead of the framework.

The problem was the server was not able to remove the cache headers. But then I found the [NginxHttpHeadersMoreModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpHeadersMoreModule) which worked just fine, so problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

if you have access to httpd.conf you could add:

```
Header set Cache-Control no-cache
Header set Expires 0
```

or if not, take a look to this [tutorial](http://tutorialpedia.org/tutorials/Apache+enable+file+caching+with+htaccess.html)

Comment: Maybe thats working in PHP too, if you have a PHP-file included in any other file

Comment: I'm not using Apache, I'm using nginx.

Comment: I don't know much about nginx...
But if you have a php-file wich gets included in any other file you can modify the header in php!

Comment: No, I tried enclosing with ob_start() and ob_get_clean() (to avoid output being sent, and be able to modify headers), then header_remove('Cache-Control'). But I'm not sure what's happening, I'm thinking Symfony2 is calling exit() or something after it's done. So after the include I can't seem to do anything.

Comment: You can try this:
    header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
This should turn caching off!